# Redirect all query to subdomain in apache

Tags: apache-2.2

I have an HTTPS site where i want to redirect all root request to www subdomain. I tried a few command but it 404 my server as it was made for .htaccess. Here is my sites-available config :

```
<VirtualHost 10.10.10.11:80>
    ServerName *.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /srv/production/www/my_app/current/public/
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 10.10.10.11:443>
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
     DocumentRoot /srv/production/www/my_app/current/public/
    <Directory /srv/production/www/my_app/current/public/>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /**********
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /**************
    SSLCertificateChainFile /*************
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of HTacess is the content of `<directory>`. i used the following config in the 443 vhost :

```
<Directory /srv/production/www/my_app/current/public/>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
</Directory>
```